# how to get the text from a text file?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I created a `Form`. The `Text` as a title for the `Form` , I want to be get from a text file `test.txt` who is saved on the Desktop, and content `Title = "the name"`. How I can do this ? And it's possible to declare  the `text file` somewhere, and all I do to be based on that file ?
If I have in `test.txt` the next rows :

```
Title= "name"
Code= " 123"
Name =" something"
```

and  if I will want somewhere in code to use this rows, all I need to do is to call code or name from `test.txt`.

Comment: how the looks like in text file?

Comment: Which version of .NET are you using?

Comment: I mentioned this thing : Title= "name" , Code="123" ....

Comment: You probably should update your question to show clearly that you are not only interested in reading a textfile, but in reading and parsing a configuration file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your file could be anywhere on your computer.

Use the following code to get the lines inside your file. just replace the path with your own.

```
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"d:\data\text.txt");
```

Then use the following code to parse each line.

```
string title = lines[0].Split(new string[] { "="}, StringSplitOptions.None)[1];
string code = lines[1].Split(new string[] { "=" }, StringSplitOptions.None)[1];
string name = lines[2].Split(new string[] { "=" }, StringSplitOptions.None)[1];
```

In order to get rid of the quotes, use the following code.

```
title = title.Replace("\"", "").Trim();
```

Now you can simply use the variable wherever you want (e.g. set the title of your form).

Update: In order to make your code cleaner you can develop a dictionary based on your config file just like following:

```
private Dictionary<string, string> readConfigs(string path)
{
    Dictionary<string, string> map = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(path);

    foreach (string line in lines)
    {
        string[] fields = line.Split(new string[] { "=" }, StringSplitOptions.None);

        if (fields.Length == 2)
        {
            string key = fields[0].Trim().ToLower();
            string value = fields[1].Trim().ToLower();

            map.Add(key, value);
        }                
    }

    return map;
}
```

And, then simply use it as follows (do not forget to change the path):

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Dictionary<string, string> map = readConfigs(@"d:\text.txt");

    string title = map["title"];

    // to get rid of quotes
    title = title.Replace("\"", "").Trim();

    this.Text = title;
}
```

Comment: I need to import something ? or to using something?

Comment: Please be more specific. If you mean any namespaces, you need to add `using System.IO;`

Comment: ok... first code I need to put in the main class, second and third one in the Form1_load ???

Comment: as a start, put them all in your `Form1_load` function

Comment: Also add `this.Text = title;` to change the title of the form

Comment: doesn't exists errors, just the fact that the text don' t appear

Comment: I think you didn't change the path of file. Please change `d:\data\text.txt` with a correct path.

Comment: Finally works. Thank you !  But if  I want to search for title not for line, how I can do this, you can help me   ?

Comment: I just updated the post to provide a cleaner solution, please check it out. this way you do not depend on the line number.

Answer (score 2):

To be more .NET conform, use the built-in configuration support:

```
using System.Configuration;

public class MyConfig : ConfigurationSection
{
    [ConfigurationProperty("Title", DefaultValue = "name", IsRequired = true)]
    public string Title
    {
        get { return (string)this["Title"]; }
        set { this["Title"] = value; }
    }

    [ConfigurationProperty("Code", DefaultValue = "123", IsRequired = true)]
    public string Code
    {
        get { return (string)this["Code"]; }
        set { this["Code"] = value; }
    }

    [ConfigurationProperty("Name", DefaultValue = " something", IsRequired = true)]
    public string Name
    {
        get { return (string)this["Name"]; }
        set { this["Name"] = value; }
    }

    private const string sectionName = "MyConfig";

    internal static MyConfig LoadConfig()
    {
        Configuration cfg = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
        MyConfig section;
        if (cfg.Sections[sectionName] == null)
        {
            section = new MyConfig();
            cfg.Sections.Add(sectionName, section);
            section = cfg.GetSection(sectionName) as MyConfig;
            section.SectionInformation.ForceSave = true;
            cfg.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Full);
        }
        else
        {
            section = cfg.GetSection(sectionName) as MyConfig;
        }

        return section;
    }
}
```

And then you can use it like this:

```
private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MyConfig cfg = MyConfig.LoadConfig();
    Text = cfg.Title;
}
```

When execute your app for the first time, a `MyAppName.exe.config` will be automatically created. Feel free to edit the attributes of the `MyConfig` node.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <section name="MyConfig" type="MyApp.Form1+MyConfig, MyApp, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" allowLocation="true" allowDefinition="Everywhere" allowExeDefinition="MachineToApplication" overrideModeDefault="Allow" restartOnExternalChanges="true" requirePermission="true" />
    </configSections>
    <MyConfig Title="name" Code="123" Name=" something" />
</configuration>
```

Comment: the class  MyConfig it's an extension class?

Answer (score 0):

```
string value1 = File.ReadAllText("C:\\file.txt");
Console.WriteLine("--- Contents of file.txt: ---");
Console.WriteLine(value1);
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this quite easily with regular expressions:

```
string GetTextfileValue(string valueName, string filePath)
{ 
    Regex nameValueRx = new Regex("^\\s*(?<name>\\w+)\\s*=\\s*\"(?<value>\\w+)\"\\s*$");
    foreach(var line in System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(filePath))
    {
        var nameValueMatch = nameValueRx.Match(line);
        if (nameValueMatch.Success && nameValueMatch.Groups["name"].Value == valueName)
            return nameValueMatch.Groups["value"].Value;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Of course this can easily be made more performant (storing the file text or values). But you could also just use an existing configuration file mechanism like this one: [Apsettings on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1xtk877y.aspx)